# Hugo not rendering list.html

Tags: html, layout, rendering, hugo

I am trying to build a simple Hugo project. The problem is that I am trying to create some basic layouts and I get an error when rendering.

Inside the /layouts/_default I have the following:

`baseof.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ .Site.Title }} | {{ .Title }}>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <p>this is a header</p>
    </header>
    <main>
        {{ block "main" . }}
            
        {{ end }}
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>this is a footer</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

`list.html`

```
{{ define "main" }}
<h2>List</h2>
{{.Content}}
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
{{ range .Pages }}
<div>
    <a href="{{.Permalink}}">{{.Title}}</a>
    <p>{{ dateFormat "Monday, Jan 2, 2006" .Date }}</p>
</div>
{{ end }}
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
{{ end }}
```

`single.html`

```
{{ define "main" }}
<h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
<h2>{{ .PublishDate }}</h2>
{{ .Content }}
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
{{ end }}
```

When I try running, I get the following error (same error both for `single.html` and for `list.html`):

> 2020/09/12 20:33:30 Failed to render pages: render of "page" failed: execute of template failed: html/template:_default/single.html: ends in a non-text context: {stateRCDATA delimNone urlPartNone jsCtxRegexp attrNone elementTitle }

Can you give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<title>{{ .Site.Title }} | {{ .Title }}>
```

should be

```
<title>{{ .Site.Title }} | {{ .Title }}</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an error directly from Go itself: [package `html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/)

### ErrEndContext: "`... ends in a non-text context: ...`"

Example:

```golang
<div
  <div title="no close quote>
  <script>f()
```

### Discussion:

> Executed templates should produce a `DocumentFragment` of HTML.
>
> Templates that end without closing tags will trigger this error.
> Templates that should not be used in an HTML context or that produce incomplete Fragments should not be executed directly.
>
> ```golang
> {{define "main"}} <script>{{template "helper"}}</script> {{end}}
> {{define "helper"}} document.write(' <div title=" ') {{end}}
> ```
>
> "`helper`" does not produce a valid document fragment, so should not be Executed directly.

Simplify your `single.html` page in order to check if your [`baseof.html` base template](https://gohugo.io/templates/base/#define-the-base-template) has the issue.

Not only `<title>` is suspect, as noted, but the `<meta>` tags are not closed either:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```